# Unity creating and loading JSON in build

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, save, load

recently made a system that lets users create their own assets during runtime, these assets are saved as JSON files, and also loaded from JSON files. It all worked in the editor and when I was playing in the editor. Also I'm using JsonUtility from newtonsoft.com

When I built the project though, it stopped working.

Heres my save function

```
public void SaveResource(ResourceAsset resourceAsset)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resourceAsset);
    string resourceModelName = "RESOURCE_"+resourceAsset.name+".json";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath+"/CustomAssets/Resources/"+resourceModelName, json);
    Debug.Log("Saved Resource");
}
```

and heres my load function

```
public List<ResourceAsset> GetResourceList()
{
    Debug.Log("finding resources..."+Application.dataPath + "/CustomAssets/Resources/");
    List<ResourceAsset> resourceList = new List<ResourceAsset>();

    foreach (var path in Directory.GetFiles(Application.dataPath + "/CustomAssets/Resources/", "*.json"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Found Resource: \n"+path);
        string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
        ResourceAsset resourceAsset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResourceAsset>(json); //convert back into object from json
        resourceList.Add(resourceAsset);
    }

    return resourceList;
}
```

I'm not sure why this doesn't work when built.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the error log to built unity projects in /%appdata%/locallow/
found the error being that the directory does not exist, therefore it needs to be validated and created if needed